# R and lubridate: do the intervals in x fit into any of the intervals in y?

Tags: r, intervals, lubridate

I'm interested in selecting only intervals in x (for me, `taskInterval`) that are also in any of the intervals in y (`campusInterval`). I'm trying to accomplish this using lubridate to get a vector of booleans to then use that to subset my dataframe.

Ideally I would do something like this:

```
taskInterval %within% campusInterval
```

and it would result in a vector of `FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE` ...

I can get it to work by selecting one interval from campusInterval:

```
taskInterval %within% campusInterval[1]
```

In the end I can use a `for` loop to go through and produce a vector for each campusInterval, but I'm thinking there's a more elegant way to do this.

Here's my data, and how I'm making my intervals. Many thanks in advance.

```
library(lubridate)

task.df <- structure(list(Start.Date = c("2014-09-01", "2014-09-01", "2014-09-01", 
"2014-09-02", "2014-09-02", "2014-09-02", "2014-09-02", "2014-09-03", 
"2014-09-03", "2014-09-03", "2014-09-03", "2014-09-03"), Start.Time = c("19:19", 
"19:41", "20:02", "07:43", "07:51", "08:03", "20:15", "07:40", 
"07:47", "08:03", "08:34", "09:30"), End.Date = c("2014-09-01", 
"2014-09-01", "2014-09-01", "2014-09-02", "2014-09-02", "2014-09-02", 
"2014-09-02", "2014-09-03", "2014-09-03", "2014-09-03", "2014-09-03", 
"2014-09-03"), End.Time = c("19:41", "20:02", "20:05", "07:44", 
"08:02", "08:19", "21:04", "18:00", "07:49", "08:28", "09:00", 
"09:38")), .Names = c("Start.Date", "Start.Time", "End.Date", 
"End.Time"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L), class = "data.frame")

campus.df <- structure(list(Start.Date = c("2014-09-02", "2014-09-03", "2014-09-04"
), Start.Time = c("07:37", "07:40", "07:40"), End.Date = c("2014-09-02", 
"2014-09-03", "2014-09-04"), End.Time = c("15:18", "18:00", "16:42"
)), .Names = c("Start.Date", "Start.Time", "End.Date", "End.Time"
), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")


taskInterval <- interval(
    ymd_hm(paste(task.df$Start.Date, task.df$Start.Time)),
    ymd_hm(paste(task.df$End.Date, task.df$End.Time))
    )

campusInterval <- interval(
    ymd_hm(paste(campus.df$Start.Date, campus.df$Start.Time)),
    ymd_hm(paste(campus.df$End.Date, campus.df$End.Time))
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this using `data.table`s `foverlaps` function

First, we will convert to `data.table` objects, create `start` and `end` intervals, and sort `campus.df` by these intervals

```
library(data.table)
setDT(task.df)[, `:=`(start = as.POSIXct(paste(Start.Date, Start.Time)),
                      end = as.POSIXct(paste(End.Date, End.Time)))]

setkey(setDT(campus.df)[, `:=`(start = as.POSIXct(paste(Start.Date, Start.Time)),
                               end = as.POSIXct(paste(End.Date, End.Time)))], start, end)
```

Then, we could simply do

```
foverlaps(task.df, campus.df, type = "any", which = TRUE) # You can also try `type = within` 
#     xid yid
# 1:    1  NA
# 2:    2  NA
# 3:    3  NA
# 4:    4   1
# 5:    5   1
# 6:    6   1
# 7:    7  NA
# 8:    8   2
# 9:    9   2
# 10:  10   2
# 11:  11   2
# 12:  12   2
```

The output tells you that rows `4:6` of `task.df` data set are within the interval in first row of `campus.df`, while rows `8:12` are within the interval of second row in `campus.df`

---

If all you want is just a logical vector indicating if the row in `task.df` is within *any* interval within `campus.df`, simply do

```
!is.na(foverlaps(task.df, campus.df, type = "any", which = TRUE)$yid)
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess this is even more reason that I need to get more comfortable with `data.table`